# How to Store comma separated Non english letters in sql string

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, cjk, chinese-locale

I have SQL Rule where it checks string starting with number. I have some non english numbers and i have included one condition.

when i store sql squery as string in row it shows ? instead letter

column datatype is nvarchar and collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

```
SELECT * Table Name WHERE (LEFT(RESELLER_CITY_NM,1) LIKE ''[0-9]'') or left(RESELLER_CITY_NM,1) in (N''一'',N''二'',N''三'',N''四'',N''五'',N''六'',N''七'',N''八'',N''九'',N''十'',N''零'',N''两'',N''千'',N''万'',N''億'',N''一つ'',N''二つ'',N''三つ'',N''四つ'',N''五つ'',N''六つ'',N''七つ'',N''八つ'',N''九つ'',N''十'',N''일'',N''이'',N''삼'',N''사'',N''오'',N''육'',N''칠'',N''팔'',N''구'',N''십'',N''백'',N''천'',N''만'',N''일억'',N''십억'',N''백억'',N''один'',N''два'',N''три'',N''четыре'',N''пять'',N''шесть'',N''семь'',N''восемь'',N''девять'',N''десять'',N''ноль'',N''сто'',N''тысяча'',N''миллиард'',N''миллион'')
```

````
SELECT * Table Name WHERE (LEFT(RESELLER_CITY_NM,1) LIKE ''[0-9]'') or left(RESELLER_CITY_NM,1) in (N''一'',N''二'',N''三'',N''四'',N''五'',N''六'',N''七'',N''八'',N''九'',N''十'',N''零'',N''两'',N''千'',N''万'',N''億'',N''一つ'',N''二つ'',N''三つ'',N''四つ'',N''五つ'',N''六つ'',N''七つ'',N''八つ'',N''九つ'',N''十'',N''일'',N''이'',N''삼'',N''사'',N''오'',N''육'',N''칠'',N''팔'',N''구'',N''십'',N''백'',N''천'',N''만'',N''일억'',N''십억'',N''백억'',N''один'',N''два'',N''три'',N''четыре'',N''пять'',N''шесть'',N''семь'',N''восемь'',N''девять'',N''десять'',N''ноль'',N''сто'',N''тысяча'',N''миллиард'',N''миллион'')```


Output:

    SELECT * from table A with (nolock)  WHERE (LEFT(RESELLER_CITY_NM,1) LIKE '[0-9]') or left(RESELLER_CITY_NM,1) in (N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'?',N'??',N'??',N'??',N'????',N'???',N'???',N'??????',N'????',N'?????',N'????',N'??????',N'??????',N'??????',N'????',N'???',N'??????',N'????????',N'???????')
````

Comment: Why??? Why comma separated?

Comment: Comma separated data will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: It is static and i want to use simple in condition. Whats wrong in above code? Please suggest workaround or best solution

Comment: _Please suggest workaround or best solution..._ Normalize your data!

Comment: Your question doesn't show us anything about the data, just the query.  It looks like you stored your query in a format that does not support Unicode, and so any characters that could not be handled were replaced with question marks.

Comment: As a test, I ran Notepad and pasted your query.  By default Notepad stores to ANSI format.  It gives a warning and then saves the text with question marks.  If I store to Unicode format, the text is preserved.

Comment: I see your quotes are all doubled.  Is this a dynamic query?  If so, I suspect that the query is being stored in a varchar.    It needs to be stored in an nvarchar.

Comment: I don't think OP is saying that the field in the database is comma-separated.  He's referring to the operand of the IN clause.

Comment: Vijay, it would help if you could show the original source code that generates the string with the question marks.

Comment: Thanks for responses i figured out the problem and tried another way. Used simple select Language from table in where condition. Worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a dynamic query.  Perhaps your `City` field is `nvarchar`, but I imagine you are storing your query in a `varchar`. Or you are missing the `N` at the beginning of the string constant. Here's an example.

```
declare @T nvarchar(1000);
declare @Q nvarchar(1000);

set @T = N'select * from TableName 
where left(City,1)in(N''一'',N''二'',N''三'',N''四'',N''五'')';

set @Q = Replace(@T, N'TableName', N'A with (nolock)' );

print @Q;

exec sp_executesql @Q;
```

Make sure the variable that holds the query text is `nvarchar`.  And make sure that the string constant starts with `N'`

Comment: Many of the strings in your list are more than one character.  LEFT(City,1) will only ever return one character.  Perhaps you should consider using LIKE.

Comment: Thanks for responses i figured out the problem and tried another way. Used simple select Language from table in where condition. Worked for me..